# Quota Attainment based on Revenue Schedule

Tags: opp-lineitemschedule, quota

We have a client that only counts revenue as it's realized vs. when it was booked and Sales reps are compensated based on when the revenue was realized vs booked.

We have Revenue Schedules established but need to be able to tie those revenue installments to the appropriate Quotas established for the users.

I believe this is possible using Customizable Forecasts but will the revenue amount for the month indicated be applied to the user's quota for that month or is the quota only looking at the Close Date of the Opportunity?

Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation:

> A quota is the monthly or quarterly sales goal that’s assigned to a user. A manager’s quota equals the amount that the manager and team are expected to generate together. The quota rollup is done manually by users and managers, and revenue or quantity data can be used. If multiple types of forecasts are enabled, each forecast type maintains separate quota information.

Quota is loaded from dataloader or API.

User can define the quota which he can achieve monthly or quarterly basis. And it is compared with Forecast categories.

[image: forecasting]

Refer [Cumulative Forecast Rollups in Collaborative Forecasts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=forecasts3_cumulative_columns_overview.htm&type=0&language=en_US)

and [Load Quota Data in Collaborative Forecasts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=forecasts3_loading_quota_data.htm&language=en_US&type=0)